# pandas groupby filtering and sampling

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df` which I want to *groupby* by some column and sample *n_items* from each group.
Groups smaller than *n_items* should be omitted and not sampled.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
n = int(1e3)
n_prod = 5
p = [0.05, 0.05, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Product": np.random.choice([f"Product_{i}" for i in range(n_prod)], n, p=p),
         "Price": (np.random.random(n) * 50 + 10).round(2),
     }
 )
```

I found a solution but I think there might exist a more *pythonic* solution that doesn't require to twice *groupby* the dataframe.

```
min_size = 150
df_sample = df.groupby("Product").filter(lambda x: len(x) >= min_size).groupby('Product').sample(min_size)
df_sample.shape
```

output:

```
(450, 2)
```

EDIT:
Note that a single *groupby* will sample 150 rows from the **entire** dataset

```
df.groupby("Product").filter(lambda x: len(x) >= min_size).sample(min_size).shape
```

output:

```
(150, 2)
```

Comment: Why do you need the second `groupby`?

Comment: @Guy otherwise, the *sample* method will be applied to the entire dataframe. I want to sample *min_size* samples per _group_

Answer (score 0):

Try this, very ugly but slightly faster with only 1 groupby:

```py
pd.concat([x[1].sample(min_size) if len(x[1])>min_size else None for x in df.groupby("Product")])
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a single `groupby`, I would put all the logic in a single function and apply it:

```py
def sample(g, size):
    return g.sample(size) if g.shape[0] >= size else None

df_sample = df.groupby('Product', group_keys=False).apply(sample, size=min_size)
```

Note that this is only marginally faster (2.38ms) than the original (double `groupby`: 2.77ms).

Another method is to use `value_counts()` to get the group sizes. As noted by @BlackMath, `value_counts()` is faster than `groupby(...).filter(...)`. It is also faster than `groupby(...).size()`. But the end result timing of the below is on par with your original solution (2.69ms vs. 2.77ms on my machine):

```py
s = df['Product'].value_counts()
df_sample = df.loc[df['Product'].isin(
    s.index[s >= min_size])].groupby('Product').sample(min_size)
```